# STS(Spring Tool Suite) variable name completion

Tags: eclipse, spring-tool-suite

[image][image]

How can i got `springNestedAOPService` suggestion?
And here is the Content Assist config
[image]

Comment: I am not sure what you mean exactly. Looks like the class for SpringNestedAOPService can't get resolved yet, so I guess that is blocking the variable name completion.

Comment: @MartinLippert SpringNestedAOPService  Class is resolved.but when i add semicolon first,then the variable name suggestion is triggered.

Comment: I would suggest to open a bug report at https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS and attach a sample project that reproduces this. From there on we can take a detailed look, ok? Thanks!!!